# Custom claims in JWT token in ASP.NET Core 2.0 api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt

In asp.net core web api, how can I retrieve custom user properties for a JWT token?

I can authenticate using this tutorial https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login, but would like to show the users full name and link to their profile pic in the header of my site.

I've extended the AppUser model to include these fields and they are being saved in the database.

From the JWT token, I can get the users id or email and then do a database looked up get their full name and profile picture, but thought it would be more efficient to get this as a custom claim, although I don't know how to do that.

This is my startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>
            (options =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();



        // jwt wire up
        // Get options from app settings
        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
        });


        services.AddMvc();

    }


}
```

Comment: you can refer to this: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore-jwt-sample/blob/master/website/TokenGenerator.cs 
although this is a manual way of generating and validating

Comment: I don't see where in that example there is a custom property stored in the token?

Comment: by the way, you need the profile picture from fb?

Comment: in the link i shared, there is a generate function with claim which generates a JWT with any claim you provide

Comment: The profile picture is stored within the application.  I've searched through the site you linked and cannot find the function you're describing!

Comment: the link shows a function called `Generate` that helps generate a JWT any list of claims you pass. However I have looked into the documentation you had sent. That part seems to be done already. You simply need add the claim as shown in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the link, under the web api for `// POST api/auth/login`, you find the following line:

```
var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
```

This generates the identity that is later used in the token. Here you can add your own claims:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "the name"));
```